# how to bulk check for opportunity in apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, map

I have a requirement where I am checking on account trigger (on account update) if any opportunity is having Closed Lost status then changing account description with count of closed lost opp

I have written some code but its not working for bulk account update and also i am not sure if its correct.can someone please help me .

```
public class AccountHandler {
    public static boolean flag=true;
    public static void  updateAcc(list<account> accList) {

        set<id>ids=new set<id>();
        for (account acc:accList) {
            ids.add(acc.id);
        }
        System.debug('ids>>>>>>'+ids);
        List<opportunity>opplist=new list<opportunity>([select id,AccountId,StageName from opportunity where accountid in:ids]);
        System.debug('opplist>>>>>>'+opplist);
        map<string,opportunity>oppmap=new map<string,opportunity>();
        for(opportunity opp:opplist){

            oppmap.put(opp.accountid,opp);
        } 
        System.debug('oppmap>>>>>>'+oppmap.keyset()+':::'+oppmap.values());
        list<account>accupdate=new list<account>();
        for(account acc:accList) {
            account accup=new account();
            accup.Id=acc.id;
            integer count=0;
            for(opportunity opp:opplist) {
                if(oppmap.get(acc.id).stagename=='Closed Lost') {
                        System.debug('***Inside If*****');
                        count++;
                        accup.description='There is'+count+' opprotunity with Closed Lost status';

                    }
                    else if(count==0){
                        accup.description='There is No opportunity with this account with Closed Lost deal';
                    }

            }
            }


        System.debug('accupdate>>>>>>'+accupdate);
        update accupdate; 
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it's not working for bulk update"? I don't see any of the typical bulkification issues here. Please go into more detail about what "not working" means.

Comment: Also, have you tried looking at using a rollup summary field to accomplish this? I think this is possible between Account and Opportunity, and should be able to solve your problem real quick and easy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Step

1.I create a Map of accountid to list of opportunity to store the data.

2.I loop through the map and add to list for update the account description

```
public class AccountHandler {
public static boolean flag=true;
public static void  updateAcc(list<account> accList) {

    set<id>ids=new set<id>();
    for (account acc:accList) {
        ids.add(acc.id);
    }
    Map<Id,List<opportunity>> mapAccountIdOpportunity = new Map<Id,List<opportunity>>();

    for(opportunity opp:[select id,AccountId,StageName from opportunity where accountid in:ids AND stagename=='Closed Lost']){
        if(mapAccountIdOpportunity.containskey(opp.AccountId)
            mapAccountIdOpportunity.get(opp.AccountId).add(opp);
        else
            mapAccountIdOpportunity.put(opp.AccountId, new List<opportunity>{opp}); 
    }

    list<account> accupdate= new list<account>();
    for(Id accId : mapAccountIdOpportunity.keySet()) {
        accupdate.add(new Account(Id = accId,description='There is'+mapAccountIdOpportunity.get(accId).size()+' opprotunity with Closed Lost status'));
    }
    if(!accupdate.isEmpty())
        Update accupdate;
}
```

Comment: absolutely perfect.thanks